# Can I hook up a model to an existing database?

Tags: sails.js

I have mongodb sitting behind an existing API and want to migrate the API to use sailsjs.

The data structure isn't anything crazy - just standard stuff using default mongodb ObjectIds as primary keys.

Will I be able to use this existing db with sails by just wiring up sails models? Do I need to specify the _id field? And, if so, what datatype should I use?

E.g. Existing mongodb with user collection with the following schema:

```
_id
name
  fname
  lname
age
```

Can I just wire up using something like the following for it to work?:

```
// User.js
var User = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
       fname: 'STRING',
       lname: 'STRING'
    },
    age: 'INTEGER'
  }
};

module.exports = Person;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: you dont have to define _id (waterline do this for you)

Waterline wants to help you using the same Functions and Models for all types of databases. A "Sub-Field" is not supported in mysql for example. So this don't work.

You can do this:

```
// User.js
var User = {
 attributes: {
   name: 'json',
   age: 'integer'
 }
};

module.exports = User;
```

If you want to validate "name" you can add your own validation:

```
// User.js
var User = {
 types: {
    myname: function(json){
        if(typeof json.fname == "string" && typeof json.lname == "string"){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
 },
 attributes: {
   name: {
      type: "json",
      myname: true
   },
   age: 'integer'
 }
};

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: I am using mongodb. A quick and dirty test of this is looking good.